# Accessing the Ubuntu terminal from Mono

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

**Background**
I'm writing an web application so I can control an *Ubuntu Server* from a web site.

One idea I had was to run the 'screen' application from mono and redirect my input and output from there.

**Running 'screen' from mono:**

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("screen", "-m");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;

var p = new Process();

p.StartInfo = info;

p.Start();

var output =  p.StandardOutput;
var input = p.StandardInput;
```

but running 'screen' with the RedirectStandardInput gives out the error:

```
Must be connected to a terminal
```

I've tried many different arguments and none seems to work with 'Redirecting Standard Input'

**Other ideas for controlling a server will be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the typical question in which you're asking how to implement your solution to a problem, instead of asking how to solve your problem. I don't think you should do hacky things like making a web app that tunnels the user actions to the server via a terminal.

I think you can bypass all that and, without writing a single line of code, take advantage of what the platform (Gtk+ in this case) already provides you:

You could run gnome-terminal in the server with the [Broadway GDK backend](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/). This way the gnome-terminal app will not run in the server, but open a web server on the port you specify. Later, you can use any WebSockets-enabled browser to control it.

This is the easiest and less hacky solution compared to the other ones offered so far. If you still are excited about using Mono for web development you still can, and you could embed this access in an iFrame or something.

(PS: If you don't want to depend on GTK being installed in the server; you could just use WebSockets in your client part of the webpage to be able to send events from the server to the client, and the library [SSHNET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to send the user's input directly through the wire.)

Comment: Well to be honest, I haven't made it work with the pty thing mentioned on sarnolds answer so this is really a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to solve the same problem is [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/).  Also interesting is [this page from the anyterm website](http://anyterm.org/compared.html) that compares different products that implement this kind of functionality.

Using shellinabox is very simple:

```
# ./shellinaboxd -s /:LOGIN
```

(this is the example given on their website) will start a webserver (on in your case the Ubuntu server).  When you point your browser to `http://yourserver:4200` you'll see a login screen, just like you would see when opening a session with ssh/putty/telnet/...  but in your browser.

You could provide the required remote access functionality to the server's shell by just including an iframe that points to that service in your application's webpage.

Comment: shellinabox dosent let me control a server, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JeremiStadler it allows you to show a login shell in a browser (that is, calling `http://yourserver:4200` will give you a "terminal window" in the browser), which means you can login and do whatever you would do in a shell.  What exactly do you mean here by "control"?

Comment: Control like in SSH, didn't know you could call another terminal from an terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`screen` will need a terminal of some sort. It's also gigantically overkill.

You may wish to investigate the `pty` program [from the Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment book](http://www.apuebook.com/) (`pty/` in the sources) to provide a pseudo-terminal that you can drive programmatically. (You'd probably run the `pty` program as-provided and write your driver in Mono if you're so inclined.) (The `pty` program will make far more sense if studied in conjunction with [the book](http://www.powells.com/biblio/72-9780321525949-0).)

The benefit to using the `pty` program, or functionality similar to it, is that you'd properly handle programs such as `passwd` that `open("/dev/tty")` to prompt the user for a password. If you simply redirect standard IO streams via `pipe()` and `dup2()` system calls, you won't have a controlling terminal for the programs that need one. (This is still a lot of useful programs but not enough to be a remote administration tool.)

There may be a Mono interface to the `pty(7)` system; if so, it may be more natural to use it than to use the C API, but the C API is what does the actual work, so it may be easier to just write directly in the native language.

Comment: Great answer! Even found an mono binding to pty :) https://github.com/mono/pty-sharp